# -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is not getting called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, xcode4

I've `UITableView` in `UIViewController` and I've connected through outlet and delegete and datasource are assigned to self.`numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are getting called i tried by using `NSLog`but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not getting call my code looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@" cellForRowAtIndexPath ");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CurrencyCell";

    CurrencyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CurrencyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    new *Obj = [appdelegate.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.CurNameLabel.text = Obj.C_Name;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"sdfnhsdfndsio;";
    NSLog(@"C_Name %@", Obj.C_Name);

    return cell;
}
```

can any one tel wer i'm making mistake Thanks in advance

Comment: have you connected delegates and datasource also in IB

Comment: What values are you returning in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: CurrencyCell is your Custom cell ??

Comment: CurrencyCell *cell = (CurrencyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: returning value of numberOfSectionsInTableView is 1 as i've 1 section and numberOfRowsInSection is array count

Comment: ya CurrencyCell is Custom cell

Comment: @RajPatil: remove that static

Comment: Multithreading enabled in the app?

Comment: "yourArray" might be empty thats why cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not getting called

Comment: @ Randeep Singh ya you ware right my array was null thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` returned are 0.If this is the case then cellForRowAtIndexPath will not get called..

From the comment above..it seems that "YourAppDelegate" variable is `null` or yourArray is `null`.Try keeping the break point on these delegates ,to check the values returned by them

Comment: What if number of rows is 3 and number of sections is 1?

Answer (score 4):

try this
add delegate and datasource in .h file like below..

```
@interface AddProjectViewController : UIViewController<
UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
.....
@end
```

after in `viewDidLoad:` put this code..

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        yourTableView.delegate= self;
        yourTableView.dataSource=self;
   }
```

and at last try this in `numberOfRowsInSection` method to return some `int` value more than 0

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourArray count];//or any int value
}
```

Comment: I did it as - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appdelegate.array count];
}

Comment: you check that your array is not nil??

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` returned are 0 or may be another reason for this

Carefully check below Points

**1** if you are creating TableView  from XIB the should set the datasource and delegate to the Files' Owner in.

if You are creating it programatically then you should set the delegate and dataSource as below and don't forget to adopt the `dataSourec` and `delegate` for `UItableView` in `.h`

```
   YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewdelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```

Put The Below line of Code just After the Line where you are creating the UITableView

```
        tableViewObj.delegate= self;
        tableViewObj.dataSource=self
```

**2** Carefully check does your `datasource`(whatever the name of Array) have data  because whenever you create the number of rows you pass the array `count as given Below

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {  
      int  numberOfRows= [datasource count];
      return numberOfRows;
      //  here check does the `numberOfRows` have nonzero value or just 0
      if it retunes 0 then cellForAtIndexPath would not call .
   }
```

I hope it'll helpful to You

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled multithreading concept in your app, even if you call `reloadData` method on `tableview` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called sometimes. So call realod method like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
```

It may work.

```
- (void)reloadTable
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If you are not in multithreading environment, then you need to make sure `tableviews` `delegate` and `datasource` are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number values in your array in "numberOfRowsInSection" method. print your array 
before returning value.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%@",returnedArray);
    return [returnedArray count];//
}
```

Also you can try sending some static number of rows in your method to check.

It looks like your array is getting null in that method.

Hope it resolves your issue.