# Is cellForRowAtIndexPath called when you use a custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a custom cell class in a tableview controller.

When I include a statement in the tableviewcontroller in `cellForRowAtIndexPath NSLog(@"method called"):` it does not seem to get called.

Is it possible that this method is not called when you have a custom cell?

**Edit:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell for row at index path called");
    NSDictionary *item= [self.getItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    //This sets place in storyboard VC
    IDTVCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.item = item;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[IDTVCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with your actual `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Also make sure your data source methods are returning a non-zero number of rows.

Comment: The numberofrowsinsection method returns however many specified, i.e. return 1 returns 1.  However, the cellforrowatindexpath does not seem to be called.

Comment: If you have non-zero sections and non-zero rows in the section then the `cellForRow...` method should be called. Have you verified that `numberOfRowsInSection:` is being called?

Comment: yes it is definitely called.  Before viewdidload according to the order in the console.  I was wondering if the custom cell affected this.

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with an added `UITableView`? If the latter, is the table view's frame set properly? How is `self.getItems` initialized?

Comment: the latter.  getItems is an NSArray property in the .h file.  It is assigned a value in viewDidLoad of an array.  It is not initialized as I understand the compiler does this for properties.  When you log it out in viewdidload it displays fine, but it returns null when logged to console from numberOfRowsInSeciton method.

Comment: Reload the table view after you populate `getItems`.

Answer (score 0):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called if no rows are returned.

[-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972452/tableviewcellforrowatindexpath-is-not-getting-called)

That is what happened in my case.

It can also not get returned if you reload table on wrong thread and in certain other scenarios.

[cellForRowAtIndexPath: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called)

However, a custom cell per se does not cause this..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - Yes, it is.

There could be n-number of reasons why `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not getting called. This may be because `delegate` / `dataSource` is not set or `UITableView` frame is not set... etc. etc.

You should easily find a solution with more online research and closure look at your code.